# Google Analytics: simple request uri filter

Tags: google-analytics

I need to exclude from the analitycs tracking all the pages that contain the url parameter no_index
Example: http://www.mysite.com/page.php?product=54&no_index=1

All I have done it's putting into the filter pattern no_intex with nothing else.
Is that right or what would be a correct regexp for this?

This is a screenshot to clarify.

Many thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set your filter pattern to this:

```
\bno_index\b
```

I do the same thing in one of my accounts to remove all requests with a specific  URL param and it works perfectly. Before saving your filter, click "Verify this filter" and it will show you the resulting effects so that you can verify it before saving.

[Here is a screenshot of the exact configuration settings in Google Analytics that should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LSV0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your Filter Pattern: `\/(.*)\&no\_index(.*)`

The Request URI starts directly after the hostname.

So your example,

http://mysite.com (hostname)
/page.php?product=54&no_index=1 (Request URI)

So, your filter pattern, no_index, would look for no_index directly after http://www.mysite.com/no_index=1